# There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive \Device\Harddisk\DR5

Tags: windows, batch-file

Problem is this : a batch program is trying to read a USB drive that has or has not got a memory flash card inserted into it. When there's none in it, a message is displayed :

"There is no disk in the drive. Please insert a disk into drive \Device\Harddisk\DR5."

in a graphical Windows style. But, at that time, the batch program is halted.

I don't mind an error being dislayed, but I don't like the halting of the program.

So, how do I solve that problem. I can't probe to it, like by means of using :

if exist X: ...

because, and yes you've guessed it, it also shows the same error, and halts the batch program. I could launch another batch program in background mode, and let that one hang, but that'll be messy.

It reminds me a lot of the old message : Abort, Retry, Fail

That was a message inside the DOS box however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
vol x: > nul 
if errorlevel 1 echo drive does not exist or is not ready
```

Comment: That works nicely, both with and without `> nul` it's not halting anywhere, and still showing relevant info. That'll do, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Building on [MC ND's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28094155/1683264), you can use [conditional execution](http://www.dostips.com/?t=Snippets.ConditionalExecution) like this:

```
>NUL 2>&1 vol x: && (
    rem drive exists
) || (
    rem drive does not exist
)
```

You can also test whether a drive exists by checking for the existence of `NUL` in the root directory.

```
if exist x:\NUL (
    rem drive exists
) else (
    rem drive does not exist
)
```

I don't have a card reader, but I tested this with my DVD drive with no disc and it worked fine.

Comment: It may work with disc drive but both `if exist X:\nul` and `if exist X:` cause the Window error if you try to access an empty card reader drive.